# Equations for step (function) have different numbers of arguments in a state machine

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, state-machine

I have this cake baking state machine in Haskell:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Ex 3: a state machine for baking a cake. The type Event represents
-- things that can happen while baking a cake. The type State is meant
-- to represent the states a cake can be in.
--
-- Your job is to
--
--  * add new states to the State type
--  * and implement the step function
--
-- so that they have the following behaviour:
--
--  * Baking starts in the Start state
--  * A successful cake (reperesented by the Finished value) is baked
--    by first adding eggs, then adding flour and sugar (flour and
--    sugar can be added in which ever order), then mixing, and
--    finally baking.
--  * If the order of Events differs from this, the result is an Error cake.
--    No Events can save an Error cake.
--  * Once a cake is Finished, it stays Finished even if additional Events happen.
--
-- The function bake just calls step repeatedly. It's used for the
-- examples below. Don't modify it.
--
-- Examples:
--   bake [AddEggs,AddFlour,AddSugar,Mix,Bake]  ==>  Finished
--   bake [AddEggs,AddFlour,AddSugar,Mix,Bake,AddSugar,Mix]  ==> Finished
--   bake [AddFlour]  ==>  Error
--   bake [AddEggs,AddFlour,Mix]  ==>  Error

data Event = AddEggs | AddFlour | AddSugar | Mix | Bake
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data Egged = HasEggs | HasNoEggs
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data Floured = HasFlour | HasNoFlour
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data Sugared = HasSugar | HasNoSugar
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data Mixed = Mixed | Unmixed
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data Baked = Baked | Unbaked
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data State = Start | Finished | Error | InProgress Egged Floured Sugared Mixed
  deriving (Eq, Show)

step :: State -> Event -> State
step Error _ = Error -- Cannot "save" an Error cake.
step Finished _ = Finished -- Once finished, the cake remains finished even if we do additional events.
step Start AddEggs = InProgress HasEggs HasNoFlour HasNoSugar Unmixed -- Adding eggs.
step Start _ = Error -- The first event must be AddEggs.
step (InProgress HasEggs flour sugar Unmixed Unbaked) = InProgress HasEggs flour sugar Unmixed
step (InProgress HasEggs HasFlour HasSugar Unmixed _) Mix = InProgress HasEggs HasFlour HasSugar Mixed Unbaked
step (InProgress HasEggs HasFlour HasSugar Mixed Baked) Bake = Finished
step Mixed Bake = Finished

-- do not edit this
bake :: [Event] -> State
bake events = go Start events
  where
    go state [] = state
    go state (e : es) = go (step state e) es

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print (bake [AddEggs, AddFlour, AddSugar, Mix, Bake])
  print (bake [AddEggs, AddFlour, AddSugar, Mix, Bake, AddSugar, Mix])
  print (bake [AddFlour])
  print (bake [AddEggs, AddFlour, Mix])
```

However, I get a strange error:

```
GHCi, version 9.0.2: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/runner/Functional-Programming-I/.ghci
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, interpreted )

Main.hs:55:1: error:
    Equations for ‘step’ have different numbers of arguments
      Main.hs:55:1-20
      Main.hs:59:1-94
   |
55 | step Error _ = Error
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
Failed, no modules loaded.
 
<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Variable not in scope: main
    • Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: your 5th clause is missing a second parameter `step (InProgress HasEggs flour sugar Unmixed Unbaked) = ...`

Comment: Looks like a misplaced close bracket on the 5th clause, as cafce25 said.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Doesn't look misplaced. The stuff that's supposed to be after the `)` isn't before it, it's just missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're learning a new language, a new environment, a new platform, etc. there can be so much to take in that it may overwhelm you. The information you need to solve most problems, however, is already present once you learn to look for them.

The error isn't strange. On the contrary, the compiler has detected an error in the code, and it tells you what the problem is:

```
Main.hs:55:1: error:
    Equations for ‘step’ have different numbers of arguments
      Main.hs:55:1-20
      Main.hs:59:1-94
   |
55 | step Error _ = Error
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Notice the file name and the numbers. `Main.hs:55:1` tells you that the problem is in the file `Main.hs`, on line `55`, on character/column `1`.

The code at that location is this:

```
step Error _ = Error -- Cannot "save" an Error cake.
step Finished _ = Finished -- Once finished, the cake remains finished even if we do additional events.
step Start AddEggs = InProgress HasEggs HasNoFlour HasNoSugar Unmixed -- Adding eggs.
step Start _ = Error -- The first event must be AddEggs.
step (InProgress HasEggs flour sugar Unmixed Unbaked) = InProgress HasEggs flour sugar Unmixed
step (InProgress HasEggs HasFlour HasSugar Unmixed _) Mix = InProgress HasEggs HasFlour HasSugar Mixed Unbaked
step (InProgress HasEggs HasFlour HasSugar Mixed Baked) Bake = Finished
step Mixed Bake = Finished
```

While there are multiple lines, it's all a *single* function, so the exact location of the problem could be on any of those lines, and not exactly on line `55`.

That's just the 'preamble' of the error message, though. After that, it says

```
    Equations for ‘step’ have different numbers of arguments
      Main.hs:55:1-20
      Main.hs:59:1-94
```

Notice the two new locations, `Main.hs:55:1-20` versus `Main.hs:59:1-94`. What happens on line `59` versus on line `55`?

And what do you make of the description `Equations for ‘step’ have different numbers of arguments`?

Consider the type declaration of `step`. What is the type of the function? How many input arguments does it take? Is that the number of arguments that the equation on line 59 takes?

Once you can answer these questions, I'm sure you can also resolve the problem.