# Implement set union as a monoid

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming, set

Here, I need to define a monoid supporting the set union operation of the set data type below.

My minimum (not) working example is:

```
import Data.List

data Set a = Set [a]
  deriving (Show, Eq)

-- emptySet is a set with no elements
emptySet :: (Eq a, Ord a) => Set a
emptySet = Set []

-- member tests if an element is in a set
member :: Eq a => a -> Set a -> Bool
member _ (Set ([])) = False
member value (Set (x : xs)) = if x == value then True else member value (Set xs)

-- add a member to a set
add :: (Eq a, Ord a) => a -> Set a -> Set a
add value (Set arr) = if member value (Set arr) then (Set arr) else Set (sort (arr ++ [value]))


instance Ord a => Monoid (Set a) where
  mempty = emptySet

unionHelper :: a -> Set a -> [a] -> Set a
unionHelper value (Set xs) [] = (Set xs)
unionHelper value (Set xs) [y] = add y xs
unionHelper value (Set xs) (y : ys) = add y (unionHelper (head ys) (Set xs) (tail ys))

instance Semigroup (Set a) where
  Set xs <> Set ys = go xs ys
    where go xs [] = Set xs
          go xs (y:ys) = add y (Set xs)
          

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print (add 1 (add 2 (add 3 emptySet)) <> add 4 (add 2 emptySet)) -- Must return [1,2,3,4].
```

Compiler has something to say about the above snippet:

```
Main.hs:47:40: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type: Set a
                  with actual type: [a]
    • In the second argument of ‘add’, namely ‘xs’
      In the expression: add y xs
      In an equation for ‘unionHelper’:
          unionHelper value (Set xs) [y] = add y xs
    • Relevant bindings include
        y :: a (bound at Main.hs:47:29)
        xs :: [a] (bound at Main.hs:47:24)
        value :: a (bound at Main.hs:47:13)
        unionHelper :: a -> Set a -> [a] -> Set a (bound at Main.hs:46:1)
   |
47 | unionHelper value (Set xs) [y] = add y xs
   |                                        ^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
 
<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Variable not in scope: main
    • Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)
```

As I am still just a beginner, I have hard times to find the right syntax. Any help, anyone?

Comment: In `unionHelper value (Set xs) [y] = add y xs` the variable `xs` is a list, not a set, so you can't `add` to it. You could try `unionHelper value (Set xs) [y] = add y (Set xs)`, or even simplyfy that to `unionHelper value s [y] = add y s`.

Comment: Your `unionHelper` has a lot of problems (`value` is unused, the signature is wrong because `add` requires `(Eq a, Ord a)`, `head` and `tail` should not be used... ). Why do you need a helper anyway? Try `(Eq a, Ord a) => union (Set a) (Set a)`. [Spoiler](https://godbolt.org/z/zGPqxW3s4). Note this is a horrendously inefficient implementation of `union`. Something like `sortUniq` from `Data.List.Unique` will do the job without too much hassle.

Comment: Start with simple instances `instance Eq a => Semigroup (Set a) where (<>) = union` and `instance Eq a =>  Monoid (Set a) where mempty = Set []`, then worry about defining `union :: Eq a => Set a -> Set a -> Set a`.

Answer (score 2):

As in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76495385/126014) let's take apart the error message. Both `Main.hs:47:40: error:` and

```
   |
47 | unionHelper value (Set xs) [y] = add y xs
   |                                        ^^
```

tell you that the problem is on line 47. (That's actually only line 25 of the code in the OP.)

Notice the two circumflexes under `xs`, indicating that the problem is with the expression `xs`, and not any of the other parts of that line.

The error message is:

```
• Couldn't match expected type: Set a
              with actual type: [a]
```

This says that, because of type annotations and/or type inference, the compiler expects `xs` to have the type `Set a`, but in reality it turns out that the type of `xs` is `[a]`. Since `Set a` isn't the same type as `[a]`, this is a problem.

Why do you think the compiler expects (or requires) `xs` to have the type `Set a`? What is the type of the `add` function. Which arguments does it take, and what types should those arguments have?

Furthermore, why do you think that the compiler infers that `xs` is `[a]`? And what could you do to address the problem?

---

If you are in doubt about any of the types, the error message tells you about those as well:

```
• Relevant bindings include
    y :: a (bound at Main.hs:47:29)
    xs :: [a] (bound at Main.hs:47:24)
    value :: a (bound at Main.hs:47:13)
    unionHelper :: a -> Set a -> [a] -> Set a (bound at Main.hs:46:1)
```

Here we see that `y` has the type `a`, `xs` the type `[a]`, and `value` also `a`.

The above information should, I hope, help you resolve the immediate problem. As [n. m. will see y'all on Reddit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m-will-see-yall-on-reddit) writes in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76512954/implement-set-union-as-a-monoid#comment134907127_76512954), however, the `unionHelper` function has more problems than just the immediate error.

Here's another tip: While experimenting with the code, *don't write any type declarations of functions.* As long as you stick to basic language features, the compiler can infer the types by itself (once they compile, that is).

It is, however, considered idiomatic to explicitly annotate Haskell functions with types. What I usually do is that I develop them without type annotations until they work and have the type I'd like them to have.

Then I get tooling (GHCi or IDE add-ins) to produce the type annotation.

Comment: I found the solution for the set union. I can run it in replit.com, but can't run it in a test file supplied by the course staff. Is it OK to edit my question?

Comment: @coderodde As a general rule in Stack Overflow, if you have a new question, you should ask a new question. These pages are publicly visible, findable by web searches, and also exist to help people in a situation that is similar to yours. If you substantially edit the OP, the page will contain answers (such as mine) that answer a prior question, but not the current one. That will be confusing to other people who later visit the page. Post a new question, ping me, and I'll take a look.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some help, I got it work:

```
data Set a = Set [a]
  deriving (Show, Eq)

-- emptySet is a set with no elements
emptySet :: (Eq a, Ord a) => Set a
emptySet = Set []

-- member tests if an element is in a set
member :: Eq a => a -> Set a -> Bool
member _ (Set ([])) = False
member value (Set (x : xs)) = if x == value then True else member value (Set xs)

-- add a member to a set
add :: (Eq a, Ord a) => a -> Set a -> Set a
add value (Set arr) = if member value (Set arr) then (Set arr) else Set (sort (arr ++ [value]))

instance Ord a => Monoid (Set a) where 
  mempty = Set []

instance Ord a => Semigroup (Set a) where
  Set xset <> Set yset = go (Set xset) yset
    where go xset [] = xset 
          go xset (y:ys) = add y (xset <> (Set ys))
```